# Portable USB application will not work on new laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, portable

I have recently purchased a refurbished laptop with windows xp home on it, and I am trying to get all my gismos to work on it. One that wont seem to comply is this handy network switching application I found called Network-Switcher (you can find it at http://wiki.nazgulled.net/en/network-switcher). I need this for my laptop especially because I frequently switch networks between locations. This would always run fine off of usb on my other laptops except not this one. The error I get is "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135). Click on OK to terminate the application.". I assumed it was a problem with my memory due to the hex address supplied, but I've run memtest and it shows nothing. This same application runs perfectly on all my other xp machines, I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: protip: Google error codes - 0xc0000135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific error is because the specified machine doesn't have the required .NET framework installed. The other machines were probably updated with newer versions of the framework which is why they worked.

From the network switcher wiki page you provided:

Requirements

```
*At least one network card so there is something to configure.
*Windows XP (SP2 or later)
*Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
```

As far as I know, XP home doesn't come with .NET Framework 2.0, it comes with a lower version. You can find 2.0 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5).